# Not getting the correct output elements from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, stdout

I'm trying to write a code that inputs a number each time into an array and than print out the result from the arrays elements but for some reason i either get an infintie loop or it prints out the same number.

```
void main() {

 char arr[SIZE];

 int k = 1;

 int i = 0;

 while (k != 0) {

   scanf("%d", &k);

   arr[i] = k;

   i++;
 }

 arr[i] = '\0';
 int b = 0;

 while (b < i) {

   printf("elements are %d\n", arr[i]);
   b++;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to print `arr[b]` and *not* `arr[i]`.

Thus, you want: `printf("elements are %d\n", arr[b]);`

As you [currently] have it, printing `arr[i]` will always print the *same* element *and* it's UB because at that point `i` is one beyond the end of the `arr` array, so the value will be unknown/undefined.